# How to find the intersection point between 2cosx and x/2

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, area, curves

I'm trying to find the solution to this because I need to find the area between the curves, but I need this intersection point to properly subtract the unnecessary parts.

I know how to do it with polynomials but with 2cosx and x/2 i just don't know what to do.

Thanks

Comment: just draw $f(x)=2cosx$ and $f(x)=x/2$, and you will see the intersection points

Comment: There is no analytic solution to that problem. Numerically, the intersection is at x≈-2.13333.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9ogj6jkpet

Comment: Well if there's no analytic solution (I think thats the only answer) I guess I can use the numeric value for the integrals. Thanks.

Comment: @Andreas yes, I see now, even after drawing not easy to find the point values

Answer (score 0):

You could use the fact that both function are continuous and the intermediate value theorem to approximate both intersection points with more "comfortable" numbers. As a start, note the following:

$$
x=-\pi, 2\cos x = -2 < \frac{x}{2}=-\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
$$
x=0, 2\cos x=2 > \frac{x}{2}=0
$$
$$
x=\frac{\pi}{2}, 2\cos x = 0 < \frac{x}{2}=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$