# Area between the curves of $2\cos(x)$ and $x/2$

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, graphing-functions, area, curves

I'm trying to obtain the area between the curve of these two functions (for $x>0$), lets call them $f(x)=2\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=x/2$ and my idea is to get the area under the curve of $f(x)$, then subtract the sum of these: the area under the curve of $g(x)$ [$0$, intersection point] and $f(x)$ [intersection point, $\pi/2$]

Is this the right way or there's an easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to plot the functions to get an understanding on how many times they intersect?

Comment: I don't think you can find the intersections exactly. Even [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(x)%3Dx%2F4) can't do it so I'm not even going to try :)

Comment: Yes i checked and only need x>0. And yes i checked the intersection is tricky but then how should i do it?

Comment: Why do you only need $x>0$? Please update the problem description to give the full problem.

Comment: *get the area under the curve of f(x), then subtract the sum of these: the area under the curve of g(x) [0, intersection point] and ${\color{red}{\text{f(x) [intersection point, π/2]}}}$.*

Why are you doing the red part? Could you carefully retype your the question? Please specify if you're looking for an exact answer or if a numerical solution suffices.

Comment: The red part is to remove an unwanted part. Please plot the functions to see if you understand my logic that might be wrong. I only need the area between the functions but as the interception point is not exact im having a bad time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the intersection point between 2cosx and x/2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3004653/how-to-find-the-intersection-point-between-2cosx-and-x-2)

Comment: Not duplicate because now I'm trying to find the area between both functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use Wolfram's approximation for the intersection point: $x\approx1.25235$.

Then you get $\approx\int_0^{1.25235} (2\cos x-\frac x2)\operatorname dx=[2\sin x-\frac {x^2}4]_0^{1.25235}=2\sin 1.25235-\frac{(1.25235)^2}4\approx1.50735$ for the area between the curves.

Comment: Thanks my brain is messed up due to lack of sleep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by subtracting the sum of what you listed, but you just need to find find the area from x=0 to the intersection point. Like what someone else mentioned, it's approximately x=1.252. Then you just take the definite integral bounded by 0 on the left and 1.252 on the right, for both equations. Subtract g(x) from f(x) and you'll have your answer.